# Change behavior for tab-key (autocomplete) when cursor is placed right after colon

Tags: sublimetext2

I want this...

```
html,body {
    padding:{tab-key-pressed!}0;
    margin:{tab-key-pressed!}0;
}
```

...to become this:

```
html,body {
    padding:    0;
    margin:     0;
}
```

But instead I get an auto-complete like this:

```
html,body {
    padding::;0;
    max-resolution: res;0;
}
```

I've been looking at the css_completions.py, but I've never learned python and I'm not man enough to make sense of things. :( I've also noticed `"auto_complete_triggers": [ {"selector": "text.html", "characters": "<"} ],`
 in the preferences.sublime-settings-file. What I really want is a `"exclude_auto_complete_triggers": ...`

So to sum up things: **Is it possible to selectively disable auto-complete when the cursor is after a colon?**

Thank you for your time!

---

**Updated solution:**
Add this line to emmet.sublime-settings:

```
"disable_tab_abbreviations_for_scopes": "source.css"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably a plugin creating some of that. Anyways, you can create a key binding and provide a context. I believe the following will work.

```
{"keys": ["tab"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "\t"}, "context": [
   { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": ":$", "match_all": true }
]}
```

Comment: You were on the money with the plugin (it turned out to be "Emmet".) I didn't succeed with the key binding (or at least it doesn't override Emmet's evil magic). So I just uninstalled emmet instead. Cheap solution I know, but hey it solved my problem. Thank you!